# Vb.exe performance time

Tags: vb6

I am running a vb.exe through automation.  In exe I have return a code which takes a data from database and saves that data into file. I ran that .exe for the first time. It took 1 mins. For testing baseline I called same .exe 5 times one after the other.  But it took nearly 10 mins to generate.

My question is if it takes 1 min for 1 report to generate then it should take 5 mins to generate 5 report but why it is taking 10 mins (more than the double).  Is there any problem while calling a exe one after the other?

Comment: It's impossible to know what is going on without a better explanation of what your code is doing.

Answer (score 0):

No, there isn't a problem with calling an exe multiple times. However, there might be a problem with the data that you're fetching or writing. Maybe you didn't close the database connection correctly upon exiting the program and this causes a delay when you try to read from the database the second time.
But then again... without a more accurate description of what your program exactly does and the relevant pieces of source code, it's very hard to be more specific...